# getting data from functions when posting with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, error-handling

I'm beginning to hate AJax, I'm finding it really difficult to get any kind of useful information back when posting with jQuery.

I have a script that adds or removes some info when a button is clicked. The jquery posts to a file which calls a function in a class. This part works, but I cant get a success message back to manipulate the front end. Here is my code.

The php works but I keep getting the error JSON.parse: unexpected character which I have googled, but my json looks ok?

jQuery

```
$('.fave').click(function(){

var favId = $(this).attr('data-user-fave');

var params = {};

params['fave_id'] = favId;
params['fav_flag'] = '1';


    $.post('index.php?link=my_applications', params, function(data){

    var data = $.parseJSON(data);

    if(data.message === 'success'){


    alert(data.flag);

    }
    else{
    alert("Fail");
    }



    });
```

code in file that jQuery posts to

```
$profile = new profile();


if($_POST['fav_flag'] == '1'){

$js = $profile->fave_user();
echo json_encode($js);


}
```

function in class profile

```
function fave_user(){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `favourite` WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['loginArr']['user_id']}' AND fave_id = '{$_POST['fave_Id']}'";

    $nr = $GLOBALS['DB']->num_rows($query);


    if($nr >= 1){

    //exists so remove


    $query = "DELETE FROM `favourites` WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['loginArr']['user_id']}' AND fave_id='{$_POST['fave_Id']}'";

    $GLOBALS['DB']->deleteQuery($query); 

    $return["message"]="success";
            $return["flag"]="del";



    return $return;

    }


    else{

    //not a fave so add



    $query = "INSERT INTO `favourite` (user_id, fave_id) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['loginArr']['user_id']}', '{$_POST['fave_id']}')";

    $GLOBALS['DB']->insertQuery($query);

    $return["message"]="success";
            $return["flag"]="ins";

    return $return;





    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `$.ajax` method: it is more advanced.

Comment: For getting error messages back? Is there an error in my code or is post just not capable of what I'm doing?